# MySQL script to import multiple csv file into multiple tables having same schema

Tags: python, mysql

I have about 50 csv files and I need to import them into 50 different database tables. I tried many thing but just couldn't find a way.The file and table names are same.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\ABC\\MySQL\\TableSchema\\xyz.csv' 
    INTO TABLE xyz 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Above code lets me load 1 file at a time but I want to automate for multiple files .I stored all table names in table fetched them in a cursor and tried to change file name and table name by concatenating string variables using cursor but it is not working. Can somebody have idea about this .

Comment: Are you executing this from Python?  What is stopping you from building each `LOAD DATA` command with the table and file you want?

Comment: Tried both in MySQL and Python.Both not working.

Comment: MYSQL: .Mysql gives error invalid sting literal ,   DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT ScripSymbol FROM tableMaster ;
OPEN my_cursor;
get_Cursor:LOOP
FETCH my_cursor INTO v_table; 
  IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
  LEAVE get_Cursor;
  END IF;     SET v_tableName = trim(v_scrip); 
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\ABC\\MySQL\\TableSchema\\'  + v_tableName
    INTO TABLE + v_tableName
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'     IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Comment: Python:if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')
        db_cursor = conn.cursor()
        
      

       query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'"+ absPath +"\' INTO TABLE " + tableName +" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (@date_time,price,open_price,high,low,Vol,changePercent)"
           + "set trade_date = STR_TO_DATE(@date_time, '%b %e,%Y');"
        db_cursor.execute(query)    gives following error IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I dont want to build Load statements for each table I want to create generic code either in MySQL or Python